# BigQuery SQL - Concatenate two columns if they are on consecutive days

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am looking for a way to adjust this sql query running in BigQuery to return single count total for Sent EventTypes that happen two or even three days in a row.

```
SELECT date(EventDate) as EventDate, EventType, count(*) as count FROM `Database.Table`
    where date(EventDate) > DATE_SUB (CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 100 DAY)
    Group by 1,2 
    ORDER by 1,2
```

Response from above Query:

```
| Row    | EventDate | EventType | count |
| ------ | --------- |-----------|-------|
| 1      | 2019-02-06|  Sent     |    4  |
| 2      | 2019-02-07|  Sent     |    5  |
| 3      | 2019-02-12|  NotSent  |    7  |
| 4      | 2019-02-13|  Bounces  |    22 |
| 5      | 2019-02-14|  Bounces  |    22 |
| 6      | 2019-03-06|  Sent     |    2  |
| 7      | 2019-03-07|  Sent     |    4  |
| 8      | 2019-03-07|  NotSent  |    5  |
| 9      | 2019-03-12|  Bounces  |    7  |
| 10     | 2019-03-13|  Sent     |    22 |
| 11     | 2019-04-05|  Sent     |    2  |
```

Response I would like to get to:

```
| Row    | EventDate | EventType | count |
| ------ | --------- |-----------|-------|
| 1      | 2019-02-06|  Sent     |    9  |
| 2      | 2019-02-12|  NotSent  |    7  |
| 3      | 2019-02-13|  Bounces  |    22 |
| 4      | 2019-02-14|  Bounces  |    22 |
| 5      | 2019-03-06|  Sent     |    6  |
| 6      | 2019-03-07|  NotSent  |    5  |
| 7      | 2019-03-12|  Bounces  |    7  |
| 8      | 2019-03-13|  Sent     |    22 |
| 9      | 2019-04-05|  Sent     |    2  |
```

Something along those line, so I am able to concatenate two counts with the EventType of 'Sent' for consecutive days, and show other EventTypes without concatenating them, such as Bounces and NotSent.

Comment: How is it possible to have 2 rows for 2019-02-06 in the first response table? Am I missing something or are they just the same day?

Comment: @Sab thanks good spot, I will try your example later on today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a query that merges all consecutive 2 days in the table.
It gives the exact same output you want.

I think you meant '2019-03-06' in the 5th row, so I fixed it in my dummy data section.

```
WITH
data AS (
  SELECT CAST('2019-02-06' as date) as EventDate, 4 as count union all
  SELECT CAST('2019-02-07' as date) as EventDate, 5 as count union all
  SELECT CAST('2019-02-12' as date) as EventDate, 7 as count union all
  SELECT CAST('2019-02-13' as date) as EventDate, 22 as count union all
  SELECT CAST('2019-03-06' as date) as EventDate, 2 as count
),
data_with_steps AS (
  SELECT *, 
    IF(DATE_DIFF(EventDate, LAG(EventDate) OVER (ORDER BY EventDate), day) > 2, 1, 0) as new_step
  FROM data
),
data_grouped AS (
  SELECT *, 
    SUM(new_step) OVER (ORDER BY EventDate) as step_group
  FROM data_with_steps
)
SELECT MIN(EventDate) as EventDate, sum(count) as count
FROM data_grouped
GROUP BY step_group
```

So, how does it work?
First, I calculate the date difference to previous day. If it's more than 2 days, I set value 1, otherwise 0 for the new column `new_step`.
Then, I calculate the cumulative sum of `new_step` column and name it as step_group.
The output of the first two steps is:
[image]

At final step, I group table by step_group and get minimum date as event date, and sum counts to obtain group count.
[image]

Edit:
To add other events without grouping by, I added a new version.
I think the most intuitive and easiest way is to use `Union All` for that problem.
So you can use that updated query to include other events without grouping.

```
WITH
data AS (
  SELECT CAST('2019-02-06' as date) as EventDate, 'Sent' as EventType, 4 as count union all
  SELECT CAST('2019-02-07' as date) as EventDate, 'Sent' as EventType, 5 as count union all
  SELECT CAST('2019-02-12' as date) as EventDate, 'Sent' as EventType, 7 as count union all
  SELECT CAST('2019-02-13' as date) as EventDate, 'Sent' as EventType, 22 as count union all
  SELECT CAST('2019-03-06' as date) as EventDate, 'Sent' as EventType, 2 as count union all
  SELECT CAST('2019-02-12' as date) as EventDate, 'NotSent' as EventType, 7 as count union all
  SELECT CAST('2019-03-07' as date) as EventDate, 'NotSent' as EventType, 5 as count union all
  SELECT CAST('2019-02-13' as date) as EventDate, 'Bounces' as EventType, 22 as count union all
  SELECT CAST('2019-02-14' as date) as EventDate, 'Bounces' as EventType, 22 as count union all
  SELECT CAST('2019-03-12' as date) as EventDate, 'Bounces' as EventType, 7 as count
),
data_with_steps AS (
  SELECT *, 
    IF(DATE_DIFF(EventDate, LAG(EventDate) OVER (ORDER BY EventDate), day) > 2, 1, 0) as new_step
  FROM data
  WHERE EventType = 'Sent'
),
data_grouped AS (
  SELECT *, 
    SUM(new_step) OVER (ORDER BY EventDate) as step_group
  FROM data_with_steps
)
SELECT EventType, MIN(EventDate) as EventDate, sum(count) as count
FROM data_grouped
GROUP BY EventType, step_group

UNION ALL

SELECT EventType, EventDate, count
FROM data
WHERE EventType != 'Sent'
```

Comment: Is there a way to add the EventType to the results ? then if so the final step for me would be to have other EventTypes in the results but only do the lag on 'Sent'.

Comment: Can you provide sample input data with other event types and expected output as well?

Comment: I have updated the question, I was also testing moving the WHERE to the subquery for the EventType of 'Sent' Though doing this still only shows the sent type ignoring say Bounces and NotSent.                                                       
data_with_steps AS (
  SELECT *, 
    IF(DATE_DIFF(EventDate, LAG(EventDate) OVER (ORDER BY EventDate), day) > 1, 1, 0) as new_step
  FROM data
  WHERE EventType like 'Sent'
),

Comment: Added the new version of the question, so you can check it.

Comment: Looks good to me, the only thing I added was an  ORDER BY EventDate to the final SELECT, I will double check the data but initially looks good, thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  The simplest method is to use `row_number()` and subtraction to identify the "islands".  And then aggregate:

```
select min(row), eventType, min(eventDate), sum(count)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by eventType order by eventDate) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by eventType, dateadd(eventDate, interval -seqnum day)
```